# Oauth2 refresh_token doesn't exists

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I use below code but when I login via Microsoft account I don't receive refresh_token. Someone can explain why?

```
$login = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?'.http_build_query([
    'client_id'              => $id,    
    'scope'                  => 'https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All',
    'redirect_uri'           => $redirect,       
    'response_type'          => 'code',
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you request `offline_access` permission.

Comment: Thanks for help. I added offline_access in scope and now I receive refresh token

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: I one more question. Google has link to check access token already expired by link `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token`. In microsoft I should use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/id-tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token?access_token` ?

Comment: You might want to post a separate question about that. You can always try to use the refresh token, and it is expired (or any other error is returned), obtain a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my all questions. I had to add offline_access to the scope.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).